# PUT request remote REST service from SharePoint-Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest

I'm trying to do a simple update in my MySQL database, I have created a REST service using JPA. The problem is, I don't know where to put the "**name/value**", the data that I want to use to update the column in the specific row, I think I'm supposed to be using ajax to do this, but I have no idea how. Please herp!

for example if I want to update the column named "comment" which has id "1" I'd do like this in  [Google Chrome REST Client Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/related) :

URL: `http://example.com/api/accounts/1`

And choose the PUT method

and as **body**:

```
{
"comment": "The Test Comment"
}
```

And it works. Now my question is, how do I do this in a SharePoint-Hosted App ( javascript)

**All I want to be able to do, is updating the comment in my remote REST service using the REST PUT method and a value from a textbox.**

This is the Ajax I've tried so far:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    url: "http://example.com/_api/clients/1",
    headers: { "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT" },
    data: '{"comment": "Dave"}'
});
```

}

Comment: I am not sure if this is gonna help, but you can use `method:POST` and in `header` add this line `X-HTTP-Method: PUT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use SP.Webproxy, as It's a cross domain call & sharepoint is http(s) and my remote web service was a regular (http).

Here's the code I used to make it work:

```
function RESTPUTCOMMENT(e) {
var newComment = document.getElementById("txtAddComment").value;
var dataObject = { 'comment': newComment }
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);

request.set_url("http://example.com/_api/accounts/" + commentId);
request.set_method("PUT");
request.set_headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" });
request.set_body(JSON.stringify(dataObject));

context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);
```

}

```
function successHandler() {
    alert('Success!!');
}
function errorHandler() {
    alert("failed");
}
```